# Grails - Mocking servletContext in Unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, servlets, applicationcontext

I am having hard time mocking servletContext in a unit test. This is how I try to do it:

```
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext
    void testSomehing() {
      def servletContext = new MockServletContext()
      servletContext.numberOfCreditProvider = 2
      [...]
    }
```

I get the following error message:

```
No such property: numberOfCreditProvider for class: org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext
```

Any help greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 servletContext.setAttribute("numberOfCreditProvider", 2)
```

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for your help. I still get the same error message though. Any other suggestion ? I have checked the API and theere does not seem to be another potential **setter method**.

Comment: Checked it again and it seems that `servletContext.numberOfCreditProvider = 2` works fine in integration tests, but not in unit tests, while `servletContext.setAttribute("numberOfCreditProvider", 2)` works in both cases. How are you running your tests, via grails test-app, or some other method?

Comment: Yes i run them this way (grails test-app -unit) to be precise. 
I'll give it another try and come back to you if I have any update

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, it seems that it's possible to set `attributes` in both unit and integration tests, but properties can only be set in integration tests.  That map-like ability does not seem to work in unit tests.